# Excel: Nested if statement doesn't remove space in second condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some few hundred thousand addresses. Some of them have particles after the integers. As in `4356 A Horse Avenue`, other are formatted normally `4358 Horse Avenue`. Some have "A" others "B".I'm trying to remove spaces between the integer and the particle: `4356A Horse Avenue`.

I've worked up this little diddy for a formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(" A ",F2),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(F2,FIND(" A ",F2)+1)," 
","")&RIGHT(F2,LEN(F2)-FIND(" A ",F2)-1),IF(FIND(" B 
",F2),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(F2,FIND(" B ",F2)+1)," ","")&RIGHT(F2,LEN(F2)-
FIND(" B ",F2)-1),F2)),F2)
```

It finds and replaces the spaces when I've got an "A" after an integer, but doesn't remove the space after a B. *However* if I remove the first `If` statement, the second one works fine and it removes the space after the integer. This is just the weirdest little bug.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(OR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999,999))={"A","B"}),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Well that works! And it's far fancier. Thanks a whole lot. Though I'm still curious as to _why_ my formula wasn't working... Is there something I'm missing? Whether you have time to answer the secondary question or not, thanks again!

Comment: `FIND(" A ",F2)` will error when A is not found, it will never even look at the second IF.  You can wrap the criteria part in ISNUMBER(): `=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" A ",F2)),...` Then is will not through the error and look at the second if.  but mine is shorter and can be expanded more easily. @J.H.

Comment: Can't you just use SUBSTITUTE to replace "A" surrounded by blanks by "A" only followed by a blank (and the same for "B"), i.e. `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F2," A ","A ")," B ","B ")`. If you want to restrict to the first instance then that's possible too using the optional 4th argument of SUBSTITUTE

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I'll definitely use yours, but I was curious as to why mine wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: @barryhoudini yes, but I was thinking of something that is easier to expand if there are more than just the two.  That method would require a new SUBSTITUTE for each choice.  Where as the one I went with, one would only need to add to the array.